# Guardar datos en la bd con cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, html, cakephp

Estoy intentando guardar datos en la base de datos con ajax y el framework cake php pero estoy medio trabado ya que no me los esta guardando en la base de datos , dejo el ajax y el metodo que guarda los datos en la bd que esta en el controlador
PD:Ambas entidades no tiene relacion directa

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#AgregarSede").on('click', function(){
            var nombre_sede=$("#nombre_sede").val();
            //console.log(nombre_sede);
            
            $.ajax({
                url:"/torneos/agregarsede",
                dataType:"json",
                data:nombre_sede,
                success: function(data){
                    //if(data.estado){

                    console.log("ok");                  
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.error("No");
                }
            });
        });

        
    });
</script>
```

Comment: que versión usas ?, tambien te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27089836/5215609

Comment: Falta el código del backend donde guardes la sede en la base de datos.